# How to print items within an array sequentially

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

I'm learning Node and I'm attempting to create a readme generator. I've created my prompts to confirm if the user would like to add gifs/images to their markdown. I've made it so that if the user confirmed then they can enter in the number and then I pass it into a for loop that generators the markdown text for adding an image. What I'm trying to do is to get it to print list style. So far I've gotten it so that it'll print but only as:

`![Alt Text](Link or File Path),![Alt Text](Link or File Path),![Alt Text](Link or File Path)`

When I'd rather it printed as

```
![Alt Text](Link or File Path)
![Alt Text](Link or File Path)
![Alt Text](Link or File Path)
```

My gut tells me to try using `forEach` but I'm not entirely sure what I should put into my callback function. Any help is appreciated.

```
const generateUsageMedia = features => {
  if (features.mediaConfirm) {
    const mediaItems = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= Number(features.mediaCount); i++) {
      mediaItems.push(`![Alt Text](Link or File Path)`);
    }
    return [...mediaItems];
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: `return mediaItems.join('\n')`?

Comment: please add the array and the wanted result.

Comment: The .join('\n') worked. Thanks @hev1

Comment: How are you calling `generateUsageMedia` Also, why are you doing a spread instead of simply returning `mediaItems `

Comment: @SSmith No problem.

Comment: @OloghoCyrilPaul I'm just now learning how to use spread and rest operators. I'll admit using it was the wrong idea but I wouldn't have learned that had I not tried and failed. I thought a forEach would work but then I couldn't figure out what to use in my callback. I looked up Split/Join but couldn't figure it out. Thankfully someone provided the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the array on the new line character (`\n`).

```
return mediaItems.join('\n');
```